# can someone explain generics in dart in plain easy english?

Tags: flutter

i know the basic generics like `List <int>l=[1,2,4,5,6];` or like this`List <String>l=["a","d","g"];`,but what is the meaning of this    `final controller=StreamController<String>();`

Comment: it means that this stream controller works with strings, so you can can add strings to its sink and listen for strings on its stream

Comment: This blog post covers StreamControllers. It also goes into detail what a StreamController<String> is. In a nutshell, it's exactly what pskink said.

https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/fundamentals-of-dart-streams/

Comment: @pskink what about this code ``` class Shape<Circle>{}``` Circle is a separate class and do you have any explanation video url for generics?

Comment: i have no idea what `Shape` and `Circle` you mean: there are no such classes in the flutter SDK - for video search any material on generics in java for example - their purpose and implementation is pretty much the same

Comment: @pskink it's just for example we have created two classes and one class name is ```Shape``` and another name is ```Circle``` and we have this code ```class Shape<Circle>{}```